# Poisson Distribution with random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, $\lambda> 0$. Get:

(a) $E  \left(\frac{1} {x+1} \right) $

Answer (a) $ \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$

I've tried to do it in $n$ ways. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you asking $\frac{1}{E[X+1]}$?

Comment: No, the question is the same as $E \left(\frac{1}{X+1} \right)$

Comment: did you try using transfert theorem ?

Comment: Ever heard of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Comment: Yeah, I think I have problems in step-by-step

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far? Please add what you have done to the question.

Comment: What is $n$? $ $

Comment: I talked about the ways I tried to solve, "n ways"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{X+1}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k+1} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^k}{k!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^\infty   \frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} = \frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda} (e^{\lambda}-1) = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{\lambda}$$

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!! I was doing the wrong calculation.